# How to send the email by using the google cloud functions without third party service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I deployed a google cloud function with Python 3.7 and it is called by google cloud scheduler every day.
 Now I need a function to send the email with specific cases while running the cloud function.
However, I didn't find any API or modules for this service provided by proper GCP. Of course there are google partner services like SendGrid. But I don't want to use it.
 So If you have any idea to send the email with cloud function, could you give me some tips?

Comment: What you're asking for is essentially the ability to deliver any email you want, from somebody else's infrastructure. Given the amount of abuse that will likely bring to whoever offers it, I doubt you'll find it in any unlimited fashion.

Answer (score 0):

GCP does not offer a general email delivery service, so you will have to consider something else.

If you want to stay within Google, you could send through gmail, but that's not part of GCP at all, and your email will always appear to come from the Google account for which it's configured.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there some site or method to learn sending email by using  programmatically or through the gmail

Comment: Questions asking for eferences for offsite products and tutorials are off-topic for Stack Overflow.  But I'm sure you can learn a lot from doing a web search.